# How to use tensorflow dataset correctly for multiple input layers with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have multiple input layers (20 input layers) and I want to use a `tf.dataset` for feeding the model. The batch_size is 16.
Unfortunately `model.fit(train_dataset,  epochs=5)` is throwing the following error:

**ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 20 array(s), for inputs ['input_2', ... , 'input_21'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(None, 20, 512, 512, 3) dtype=int32>]...**

I assume, that keras wants a shape like **(20,None,512,512,3)**.
Has someone an idea to this problem or how to use tf.datasets correctly for a model with multiple input layers?

```
def read_tfrecord(bin_data):
    for i in feature_map_dict:
        label_seq[i] = tf_input_feature_selector(feature_map_dict[i])
    img_seq = {'images': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string)}
    cont, seq = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(serialized=bin_data, context_features=label_seq, sequence_features=img_seq)
    image_raw = seq['images']
    images = decode_image_raw(image_raw)    
    images = tf.reshape(images, [20,512,512,3])
    images = preprocess_input(images)
    label = cont["label"]
    return images, label

def get_dataset(tfrecord_path):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=tfrecord_path)
    dataset = dataset.map(read_tfrecord)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    return dataset

def create_model():
    nets =[]
    inputs=[]
    # Set up base model
    base_ResNet50 = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top= False, input_shape=(512, 512, 3))    
    for images_idx in list(range(0,20)):
        x = Input(shape=(512,512,3))
        inputs.append(x)
        x = base_ResNet50(x)
        nets.append(x)
    maxpooling = tf.reduce_max(nets, [0])
    flatten = Flatten()(maxpooling)
    dense_1 = Dense(10,activation='sigmoid')(flatten)
    predictions = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Thanks in advance.

With a small modification of Niteya's idea the test toy-model runs the training. Great!

But I am still not happy with this solution, because all 20 images belong to one object and so far I understand this solution I have to create 21 tfrecords. By that, the informations of one object will be distributed overall these files.
I would like to have a more easy solution, where all the informations of an object are in only one tfrecord.

This testing toy-model works!!!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x_1 = Input(shape=(100,100,3))
x_2 = Input(shape=(100,100,3))
inputs = [x_1,x_2]
flatten_1 = Flatten()(x_1)
flatten_2 = Flatten()(x_2)
dense_1 = Dense(50,activation='sigmoid')
d1_1 = dense_1(flatten_1)
d1_2 = dense_1(flatten_2)
nets =[d1_1,d1_2]
maxpooling = tf.reduce_max(nets, [0])
d2 = Dense(10,activation='sigmoid')(maxpooling)
predictions = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(d2)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])

for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name)

input_d = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.random.normal([16,100,100,3])) for i in range(2))) 
output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.ones(16))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_d, output))

model.fit(dataset,epochs=5)
```

Using Niteya's second idea with the function tf.split is a good solution.
Niteya, thank you very much.

````
inputs = Input(shape=(20,512,512,3))
for x in tf.split(inputs,num_or_size_splits=20, axis=1):
        x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,512,512,3])
        x = base_ResNet50(x)
        nets.append(x)```  
and
````

BATCH_SIZE=1
model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=5)

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using `tf.data.Dataset.zip`? Your model needs to be fed 20 different inputs so zip them together, then zip that dataset with the output, which also needs to be zipped.

I am using random inputs but you should get the method from it.

```py
    input_d = tf.data.Dataset.zip(tuple(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.random.normal([16, 512,512,3])) for i in range(20))) 
    output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf.ones(16))
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_d, output))
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip

Edit: Using split, something like this could be done. Pass the entire the dataset, and then split it(You may need to use axis).

```py
    for i in tf.split(tf_record_Input, 20):
        x = base_ResNet50(i)
        nets.append(x)
```

Comment: Hi Niteya, thank you for your idea :-). Unfortunatly, my reputation is to low to be allowed to give you a possitiv vote, but I hope users with more previlege and power will do that for me ;-). Does I understand your idea correct that I have to create 21 tfrecords to produce the 21 dataset and zip them together. By that, the informations of one object will be distributed overall these files. Do you have another more easy and beautiful idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can always accept a larger input and then split them. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split will be your friend. Then use a for loop to internally assign them to the resnet models. The rest should remain the same.

Comment: `inputs = Input(shape=(20,512,512,3))
for x in tf.split(inputs,num_or_size_splits=20, axis=1):
        x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,512,512,3])
        x = base_ResNet50(x)
        nets.append(x)`                                                                                                       Now, I getting the following error,  OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:539 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape

Comment: That's an out of memory error. Try it with a lesser number of conv nets and see what happens. This is definitely odd behaviour.

Comment: It must be something as you said. But the base_ResNet50 
 is ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top= False, input_shape=(512, 512, 3)) with all layers trainable=false, so I would expect that only one ResNet50 is in memory sharing the weights. I had assume that one RestNet50 = ca. 190 MByte. I will test it with a small custom made conv net.

Comment: Why would you want them to share weights. If they are training the same model, why are you passing them separately?

Comment: I have 3d-geometries, which I like to analyse. For each 3d-object, I have 20 views (images). By that, I like to create a multi-view-cnn based on a pretrained cnn. Then I like to transfer learn and fine tune it, depending on the 3d-geometry.

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood your use case. Well, if you look at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f0c0c877babe95253667783653e6540219609cf9/keras/engine/functional.py#L404 , you will see that the Keras application will always instantiate a new model. So either you start using Model subclassing, which is tedious for large architectures like ResNet or you copy the internal layers from the first to each and every next one, which will make very messy code.  If you are ok with it, the authors have shared their pytorch code which is much easier to understand.

Comment: Another technique that you could use was to modify the loss function. Instantiate one resnet model, pass 20 images as a batch. But during your loss calculation instead of dividing straight by 320, split them and then calculate their loss.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. What do you mean by " loss calculation instead of dividing straight by 320, split them and then calculate their loss". I not really understood this point. There exists also a tensorflow implementation by WeiTang https://github.com/WeiTang114/MVCNN-TensorFlow.

Comment: The TensorFlow code implements the entire model as I had said earlier and is an option. NVM the loss method, I just realized it won't work.

Comment: Hi Niteya, your split idea is training now with a batchsize of 1 and removing a corrupt data element. Thank you very much for your ideas and help. Now, I have to find a way to increase to performance :-).

Comment: My recommendation for such a custom implementation would be to subclass the model. Whenever I come across a complex problem like this. I immediately use that method because of its sheer flexibility. I highly recommend that you try it because it will perform really well and will be clean. It is just a bit of work to do it.